# ANSI C - Deallocation of nested BER TLV elements created using dynamic array

Tags: c, asn.1

To build nested TLV elements (e.g., 6F1A840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A5088801025F2D02656E), I'm using the following data structure:

```
typedef struct Element
{
    int16_t nTag; // Tells you if pValue points to a primitive value or constructed one 
    uint16_t nLength;
    void *pValue; // Could be either unsigned char* or TlvElement*
} TlvElement;
```

How can I implement a function that properly deallocates the memory used by the nested TLV elements?

```
// Let's build TLV data: 6F04A5020000
TlvElement *pTlvElement = (TlvElement*)malloc(sizeof(TlvElement));
pTlvElement->nTag = 0x6F;
pTlvElement->nLength = 4;
pTlvElement->pValue = malloc(sizeof(TlvElement)); // pValue points to another TLV element

TlvElement *pTlvElementChild = (TlvElement*)pTlvElement->pValue;
pTlvElementChild->nTag = 0xA5;
pTlvElementChild->nLength = 2;
pTlvElementChild->pValue = malloc(2 * sizeof(unsigned char)); // pValue points to a byte array
memset(pTlvElementChild->pValue, 0, 2);

Deallocate(pTlvElement);

//free(pTlvElementChild->pValue);
//free(pTlvElement->pValue);
//free(pTlvElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just deallocate it in the order you gave in the commented lines:

```
free((TlvElement *)(pTlvElement->pValue)->pValue);
free(pTlvElement->pValue);
free(pTlvElement);
```

The function `free(void *)` takes a `void *`, so the compiler wont complain. The only cast you need is to access the field `pValue` of the child element.

A word of caution: unless the `tag` already marks this, you might consider to add keep somewhere that the element does indeed contain a child element.

Assuming the value of `->nTag` field can be used for this, you can deallocate the child elements recursively:

```
void Deallocate(TlvElement *e)
{
  if (e->nTag == 0x6f)
    Deallocate((TlvElement *)e->pValue);
  else
    free(e->pValue)
  free(e);
}
```

You might want to take precautions against endless recursion, though.

Comment: @fork0-Thanks for your response but I want the Deallocate() function to be used for any TLV data deallocation (regardless of however nested/complicated that TLV data might be).  I think what I'm not sure is how to traverse every single element.

Comment: @jpen: unless you provide this information in the element itself - you cannot. Can you say that by looking at nTag?

Comment: @fork0-I've decided to use an arbitrary tree rather than dynamic array but thanks for your help anyway!